# using unix system calls in cpp

Tags: c++

I am new to cpp, I have a small problem,
I have a cpp file and it contains open(), read() & close() & some other methods as public members. Now I wanted to use the 'read' unix system call in one of the methods But if I do so (in some method) its pointing to class member variable 'read()' and gives compilation error.
So, how to use the unix system calls such as 'open, read, close' in the cpp? if not so any other alternative to use?

Thanks-opensid

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question -- using POSIX system calls does not change when you move to C++ -- it's the same as it is in C.

Comment: @Billy, But How shall I use in the CPP member functions? its not allowing me to call to unix system calls and thorughs compile error because while compile time its pointing to member function as the signature dont match. do you think some alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in a class that has a method read(), and you want to access a function read() in the global namespace, use ::read().

Comment: "it worked... Thanks alot" is usually expressed on StackOverflow as a green tick next to the answer ;-)

Comment: ...and be thankful that `read` isn't a `#define`'d constant that evaluates to either `readA` or `readW` based on another preprocessor constant.

Answer (score 1):

Try ::read(). The double colons take you to the top empty namespace.

Comment: Err.. it wouldn't be much use if it was empty. :/

Comment: @Billy: Close your eyes and take yourself to the empty global namespace… isn't that nice?

Comment: Empty global namespace is the natural habitat of the unicor ;) And the former is as abound as the latter.